# How to make sure object is properly initialized without constructor?

Tags: c#

I would have to create a constructor with great amount of parameters like:

```
new MyClass(param1, param2, param3, ..., param100);
```

Is there any way to initialize object like that in a gradual manner, like:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.Prop1 = val1;
obj.Prop2 = val2;

obj.checkIfInit() //I am not sure how to do that.
```

How to verify that it is initialized properly if the crazy constructor is not used?

Comment: Why have you got so many individual parameters? Is that not the issue here?

Comment: The parameters are required to initialize the class. 100 is just an example here. It can be less. I just need to verify at some point object is initialized properly.

Comment: **In theory** you could go through the properties and check if they are not equal to their default value. But that's a bad idea. Once you've called a constructor you expect the object to be 'ready', to be fully initialized. Every property that can be set afterwards is just optional. Means: All the properties that **must** have a proper value should be set in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you should really not have a constructor with so many parameters - although with Dependency Injection for a data model type class, you do often end up with a lot of parameters. In that case, it's usually best to group the parameters into subsets encapsulated into their own classes.

Notwithstanding that advice, you can address the issue with a variant of the ["Builder Pattern"](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/builder-design-pattern-dotnet).

For example, given:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int prop1, string prop2, DateTime prop3)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        Prop3 = prop3;
    }

    public int      Prop1 { get; }
    public string   Prop2 { get; }
    public DateTime Prop3 { get; }
}
```

First note that it has no default constructor and the properties are all read-only, making this class immutable (often a good idea).

(I have omitted parameter checking for brevity.)

Now you can write a helper class to build the object:

```
public sealed class MyClassBuilder
{
    public MyClass Build()
    {
        if (!_prop1Set || !_prop2Set || !_prop3Set)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not all properties set.");

        return new MyClass(_prop1, _prop2, _prop3);
    }

    public MyClassBuilder Prop1(int value)
    {
        _prop1    = value;
        _prop1Set = true;

        return this;
    }

    public MyClassBuilder Prop2(string value)
    {
        _prop2    = value;
        _prop2Set = true;

        return this;
    }

    public MyClassBuilder Prop3(DateTime value)
    {
        _prop3    = value;
        _prop3Set = true;

        return this;
    }

    int      _prop1;
    string   _prop2;
    DateTime _prop3;

    bool _prop1Set;
    bool _prop2Set;
    bool _prop3Set;
}
```

Each method for setting a property returns `this`, to enable fluent use like so:

```
var builder = new MyClassBuilder();

builder
   .Prop1(1)
   .Prop2("test")
   .Prop3(DateTime.Now);

var myClass = builder.Build(); // Throws if not all properties set.
```

This gives you a great deal of flexibility for parameter validation and allowing some parameters to be omitted (by providing suitable defaults).

A real-world example of a builder class is [Autofac's ContainerBuilder class](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/717248.htm), usage of which [is described here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html).

Comment: The builder pattern would be great if there was a way to verify that mandatory properties were set at some point. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ed22 The code I posted is actually checking that the mandatory properties were set - see the lines `if (!_prop1Set || !_prop2Set || !_prop3Set) throw new InvalidOperationException("Not all properties set.");`

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a high amount of repetition in your constructor, which is almost always an indicator of bad design. If possible, why not use a collection type, like an array:

```
new MyClass(paramArray);
```

Nice and clean.

If you really need that much parameters, you can usually group them together in categories. Make classes for each of them and pass those instances in. It will make use later on much easier too.

Comment: My params are not all one type so can't use it. Also they do not <belong> to one array.

Comment: Then group them into classes.

Answer (score 0):

Make all paramter to a class or struct , to help you make controctor be clean.

```
public class InitData
{
    Parmter ....
}

new MyClass(InitData data);
```

Or use paramters

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(params[] paramters)
    {
        foreach(p in paramters)
        { ... }
    }
}
```

Possbie do not make a 'crazy controcter' is best soultion I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Equals in order to check the default value:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static readonly MyClass DefaultInstance = new MyClass();

    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    // Etc...

    public MyClass() {
        this.Val1 = 10;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + Val1.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Val2.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        var other = obj as MyClass;
        return other?.Val1 == this.Val1 && 
               other?.Val2 == this.Val2;
        // Etc...
    }
}
```

Then you can just check using:

```
if (MyClass.DefaultInstance.Equals(instanceToCheck)) {
... // All defaults
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# compiler implicitly gives you a default constructor if you are not writing any Constructor for a class.

Now, If you are explicitly giving an Constructor now the C# Compiler will not provide you any Constructor.

i.e you have only One Constructor with you =>MyClass(param1, param2, param3, ..., param100);

Now, You are trying to Create the object without any Parameters.=>MyClass obj = new MyClass();

So, there will be error every time you compile as the Compiler does not find this type of empty overload of the Constructor which one is not taking any value.
To avoid this use an empty constructor explicitly.

Look for the Following example.

```js
            Class1 cs = new Class1();
            cs.x = "xyz";
            cs.y = "zyx";

            if(cs!=null)
            {
                //This checks the Object is created or not i.e Reference is created.
                Console.Write("I'm intialized");
                

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm not initialized");
            }
```

And the Class for Class1 follows

```js
    class Class1
    {
        public string x;
        public string y;
        public Class1(string x,string y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Class1()
        {

        }
    }
```

Check it.